# Using microtext.js inside React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use microtext.js library in my create-react-app App.

I place this in my index.html

```
<script  src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/microtext.js"></script>
```

Now Microext is showing in my console.

But when I try to use it in my component.

```
<p className="card-text">{Microtext.breakSentence("Gaal Dornick")}</p>
```

I am getting Error: `./src/components/RecipeList.js
  Line 29:  'Microtext' is not defined  no-undef`

Please help how can I do that.

Thanks

Edit-1
My Folder structure
[image]

Comment: try `webpack.ProvidePlugin` if you are using `webpack`: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery

Comment: Will you please post the folder structure and where the `microtext.js` is placed

Comment: @VivekDoshi, Please see the edit. I have added folder as image. My components are inside src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer.
I have to use `window` object to access external `non npm js` libraries.
e.g.

```
console.log(window.Microtext.breakSentence("Gaal Dornick"))
```

And this works perfectly. `["Gaal", "Dornick"]`